# Moving text using an environment

Tags: environments

Is it possible to create environments or something similar to get the behavior:

Example input

```
\section
\begin{problem}
    problem 1
    \begin{solution}{section 1}
       solution 1
    \end{solution}
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
    problem 2
    \begin{solution}{section 1}
       solution 2
    \end{solution}
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
    problem 3
    \begin{solution}{section 2}
       solution 3
    \end{solution}
\end{problem}
```

Desired output:

```
 problem 1
 problem 2
 problem 3

 section 1
    solution 1
    solution 2
 section 2
    solution 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think to something like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\newtheorem*{printsolution}{Problem \problemnumber}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{solution}{+b}
 {
  \angelos_solutions_grab:n { #1 }
 }
 {}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printsolutions}{}
 {
  \angelos_solutions_print:
 }

\seq_new:N \g_angelos_solutions_seq
\int_new:N \l_angelos_solutions_section_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \angelos_solutions_grab:n
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_angelos_solutions_seq
   {
    \angelos_solutions_item:nnn
     { \int_to_arabic:n { \value{problem} } }
     { \int_to_arabic:n { \value{section} } }
     { \exp_not:n { #1 } }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \angelos_solutions_item:nnn
 {
  \int_compare:nF { #2 = \l_angelos_solutions_section_int }
   {
    \subsection*{Section~#2}
    \int_set:Nn \l_angelos_solutions_section_int { #2 }
   }
  \cs_set:Npn \problemnumber { #1 }
  \begin{printsolution}
  #3
  \end{printsolution}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \angelos_solutions_print:
 {
  \section*{Solutions}
  \seq_map_function:NN \g_angelos_solutions_seq \use:n
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\begin{problem}
First problem in the first section
\begin{solution}
Solution to the first problem in the first section
\end{solution}
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
Second problem in the first section
\begin{solution}
Solution to the second problem in the first section
\end{solution}
\end{problem}

\section{Second}

This section has no problems

\section{Third}

\begin{problem}
First problem in the third section
\begin{solution}
Solution to the first problem in the third section
\end{solution}
\end{problem}

\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

The solution is stored in a sequence, together with the current problem number and the current section number.

The `\printsolutions` command delivers the contents, issuing when necessary a `\subsection*` command.

[image]

You can use `nameref` if you want to repeat the section title.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{nameref}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\newtheorem*{printsolution}{Problem \problemnumber}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set_eq:NN \angelos_section: \section
\cs_new_protected:Nn \angelos_nameref:n { \nameref { #1 } }

\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sO{#3}m}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {
    \angelos_section: * { #3 }
   }
   {
    \angelos_section: [#2]{#3} \label{angelosautolabel\int_to_roman:n { \value{section} } }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{solution}{+b}
 {
  \angelos_solutions_grab:n { #1 }
 }
 {}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printsolutions}{}
 {
  \angelos_solutions_print:
 }

\seq_new:N \g_angelos_solutions_seq
\int_new:N \l_angelos_solutions_section_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \angelos_solutions_grab:n
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_angelos_solutions_seq
   {
    \angelos_solutions_item:nnnn
     { \int_to_arabic:n { \value{problem} } }
     { \int_to_arabic:n { \value{section} } }
     { \exp_not:N \protect \exp_not:N \nameref {angelosautolabel\int_to_roman:n { \value{section} } } }
     { \exp_not:n { #1 } }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \angelos_solutions_item:nnnn
 {
  \int_compare:nF { #2 = \l_angelos_solutions_section_int }
   {
    \subsection*{Section~#2\ --\ #3}
    \int_set:Nn \l_angelos_solutions_section_int { #2 }
   }
  \cs_set:Npn \problemnumber { #1 }
  \begin{printsolution}
  #4
  \end{printsolution}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \angelos_solutions_print:
 {
  \section*{Solutions}
  \seq_use:Nn \g_angelos_solutions_seq {}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\begin{problem}
First problem in the first section
\begin{solution}
Solution to the first problem in the first section
\end{solution}
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
Second problem in the first section
\begin{solution}
Solution to the second problem in the first section
\end{solution}
\end{problem}

\section{Second}

This section has no problems

\section{Third}

\begin{problem}
First problem in the third section
\begin{solution}
Solution to the first problem in the third section
\end{solution}
\end{problem}

\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Does compiling your code require anything special? I failed compiling it using pdflatex.

Comment: @Angelos This requires an up-to-date TeX distribution.

Comment: I have run TeX Live Utility and updated all packages but I still get the error "LaTeX3 Error: Unknown argument type 'b' for the command '\environment(LaTeX3) solution'. {}". Do I have to do another type of upgrade?

Comment: @Angelos If you get that error, it means your system is not up-to-date. What OS are you using?

Comment: I understand. I am using Mac.

Comment: @Angelos I too. Install MacTeX 2020

Comment: After having upgraded I can compile without any problem. Is it possible to modify the example such that the section names in the solution inherit the section names of the problems? For example, in your example "problem 1" is in section "First", but in the "Solutions"-section "problem 1" is under "Section 1" instead of a section called "First".

Comment: @Angelos I added the repetition of the section titles.